# Why are the weekday Shacharit chazzan switching locations the way they are?

Tags: synagogue, chazzan-prayer-leader, shacharis-morning-prayer

I'm using Nusach Ahskenaz weekday prayers in this discussion.

Based on what I have seen in most shuls, I have seen a shaliach tzibbur switch at these locations:

Before *Yishtabach* - I would think that the bracha is part of *Pesukei Dezimra*. Wouldn't it make sense to keep the chazzan who said the opening *bracha* (Baruch She'amar) say the closing one and Kaddish as well. Then switch just prior to *Barchu* which starts the *Birkat Kri'at Shema*?

Before the 2nd *Ashrei* - This does begin a new "section", but, I'm not sure I see the reason for switching, here, specifically, vs. e.g., just before saying *Tachanun*. I.e., what's special about this location more than another?

When Hallel is said, I frequently see them switch to another Chazzan for only Hallel. Then the one who said the *Amidah* returns to say the Kaddish - Two questions - Why switch for Hallel, and why doesn't the Hallel chazzan say Kaddish?

I've occasionally seen additional switches just before *Baruch She'amar*, as well. However, frequently, it's form a kid (under Bar Mitzvah) to an adult. I'm not as concerned, here. Technically, I read (there's another M.Y. question about this) that a chazzan is really not needed for *Psukei Dezimra*, anyway. (Maybe that's part of the reason for the switch?)

Are there any other places where switching would be allowed or are they restricted to just these places?

Comment: I think that if the switch was after Yishtabach, the chazan would have to say kadish before borchu, which would lead into borchu and not allow the switch.